# Create password breaker for iPhone backup files

Tags: iphone, backup, password-recovery, password-retrieval

I lost all my photos and contacts in my iPhone, when I had to do a recovery, after I did an update. When trying to restore my old data from backup file, it prompted me for password. I have tried all passwords I normally use, but to no availe.

I have tried programs like Elcomsofts password breaker. The problem is that they only allow you to search for either words from a dictionary, or the letters/numbers you tell it. But you can not (not that I have found at least) create some kind of regular expression to limit the search.

I have am pretty sure I know the structure of my lost password = A combination of words and random letters/numbers. So I think that a regular expression could make it realistic to get the password. So this is why I turn to you.

I am trying to create a simple program in .NET, C#. A console application, or a basic MVC-application. An application where I would loop through all the combinations my regular expression would come up with. That part I think I know how to do. The problem is:

How can I test the backup file/folder with the passwords? I have tried to open the file using Process.Start(filepath), but when I point to the plist file, it says there is no program to open the file with. And even if I manage to open the file with say Notepad, how do I test the password? Is it a parameter to send in? And what kind of reply will I get back? I mean how do I know if a password is a match or not?

In short: 
I need to create a program (or find one that works), that can loop through a regular expression limited list of passwords, and try if they match the one in my iPhone backup file.

I am sorry that my question is long and a bit untechnical. I am a bit new to this. I have done webbprogramming, but not much windows/file related programming. Any help you might be able to give would be highly appreciated, as I am a bit desperate to get photos of my daughter and contact info back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if Elcomsoft allows you to wipe out the dictionary and provide your own. Then, 
generate all of the possibilities and make that your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply! That sounds like an excellent idea! Cause I can open the dictionary. It is just a linebreak separated list of words, and combos. So I will try your advice. Keeping my fingers crossed it will work. Thanks again for your answer!:=)

Comment: I am trying to implement it now. I get back with (hopefully) a succesful result later! :=)

Comment: Hey Lou! 

Thanks again for your answer. I created a program that allowed me to choose what password versions to use. It created nice LONG dictionary fiels with about 6 million words in it. Elcomsoft had no problem using my modified dictionary. I have how ever still not been able to find the right combination, but I HOPE it is only a matter of time, until I find the right formula. :=) 

I do not have enough "cred" here to up-vote your answer, but here is a big thumbs up, *, +1 and like! :=) Thanks for giving me a good solution!